# Html & CSS criar menu responsivo

Tags: html5, css3

Preciso da vossa ajuda, estou a programar um site, quero que ele fique responsivo. Criei uma barra, esta está responsiva, e coloquei o menu na horizontal do lado direito do ecrã, do lado esquerdo coloquei o logo do meu site, mas este não fica responsivo...
o código que tenho é o seguinte:

```
<body>
  <div class="barra">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="home.html"><img src="logopequeno1.png"  width="50%" height="10%"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="novo.html">Sobre</a></li>
        <li><a href="portefolio.html">Portefólio</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactos.html">Contactos</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Porque não consigo colocar o logo responsivo tal como o menu?

Comment: Responsivo é uma palavra que não quer dizer nada na prática. Seria legal você explicar o que quer que aconteca de fato, aumentaria a chance de sairem respostas boas.

Comment: Não vale a pena pra você usar algum framework que facilite isso? Como o bootstrap, por exemplo?

Comment: Poste mais do seu código, seu CSS por exemplo. E como o @Bacco disse, seria melhor você explicar o que quer que aconteça com o seu layout.